# How can I expand a partition (with my Grub boot loader on it) and make sure it still boots after the fact?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, hard-disk

I have a 2TB harddrive which I restored a Clonezilla Ubuntu OS image on it, the image was of a 512GB disk, so now my system sees the 2TB drive as a 512 with 1.5TB of free space.  I looked into it and some suggestions is to boot from a USB then install gparted then merge them but then it said that it might mess up with the grub and since it’s the OS system drive I don’t want to mess it up that’s why I am seeking advice before trying things.

And here is the result of `sudo lsblk`

[image]

So I wonder how I can allocate the 1.5TB to the rest of the OS harddrive so my system sees the drive as 2 TB not 512GB without messing up GRUB?

[image]

Comment: No research effort shown - what have you already tried? Where did that fail?

Comment: @Panki I looked into it and some suggestions is to boot from a USB then install gparted then merge them but then it said that it might mess up with the grub and since it’s the OS system drive I don’t want to mess it up that’s why I am seeking advice before trying things.

Comment: Tak: what you replied to @Panki is the type of missing info in OP. If your boot volume is on the partition you which to extend, you may have issues and that could be the subject of the question: "how can I expand a partition (with my Grub boot loader on  it) and make sure it still boots after the fact ?" You might want to read about how to restore a boot loader [and so on](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB)... If you boot info region on disk is NOT on the partition to extend, then you may only have to check that your UUIDs in your `/etc/fstab` are as expected after GParted did its surgery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unmount the swap and logical partition
2. use the gparted to delete the partitions
3. extend your root partition using gparted
4. finally create a logical partition and a swap partition in it
5. Verify/modify the /etc/fstab so that UUID matches

---

Here is a small illustration.Modify for your case accordingly.Feel free to ask if you face any error/doubs and accept the answer if it helped

---

if you are doing this from system itself then unmount the swap partition before continuing

if doing this from live usb make sure every partition in unmounted ofc ):

---

1. current situation,disk in mbr and swap in lartition

[image]

2. start by deleting the swap partition

[image]

3. delete the logical partition

[image]

4. resize your root ext4 partition

[image]

---

here you might get something like

[image]

well read it carefully; basically if anything happens during resizing then you are done and your data is gone );

---

5. root partition size before resizing

[image]

6. root partition size after resizing

[image]

7. now it should look like this

[image]

8. create your logical partition

[image]

9. allocate te size of logical partition

[image]

10. create a swap partition in logical partition

[image]

11. allocate swap partition size

[image]

12. finally it should look like this.check the list of pending processes

[image]

13. apply the changes

[image]

14. all done , this is how it should look like

[image]

15. correct the UUID of swap partition in `/etc/fstab`

[image]

Comment: Do I need to boot from a USB and install gparted then do these steps or?

Comment: @Tak you can do this from ubuntu itself {you can simply resize ext4 while ussing it}; i am adding more examples hang on

Comment: Yes if you could please add a step by step example to follow, thanks a ton

Comment: many thanks. In your last step when you say "correct the UUID of swap partition" you copy it from the disks window then paste it where?

Comment: @Tak in the /etc/fsatb file you will find an entry related to swap partition.you have to replace it's uuid; if you want help with that - attach the contents of /etc/fstab in you question {and also attach the uuid of root and swap after resizing}

Comment: Thanks again. So now shall I follow your instructions while running the OS? or shall I boot from a USB Ubuntu?

Comment: @Tak do it directly from the os itself

Comment: Many thanks for your help and detailed answer, can you please check my other question found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679247/error-cannot-have-overlapping-partitions thank you in advance