# Clonezilla: cannot have overlapping partitions

Tags: partition, disk, nvme

I am trying to image my Ubuntu disk using Clonezilla and it fails because I get an error saying:

> error cannot have overlapping partitions

Below is how my disk is set up and the `lsblk`output:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1         7:1    0  42,2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14066
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:3    0   976M  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 952,9G  0 part /
```

And here is the output of `fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953,9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6e617337

Device         Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *          2048 1998407679 1998405632 952,9G 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p2      1998409726 2000397734    1988009 970,7M  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      1998409728 2000408575    1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Sola
```

And here is how it appears in gparted:

[image]

Any advice how to fix this error so I can image/save my disk?

Comment: Please describe what you have plugged into your PC/NTB, if only this disk, and want to save it (for later use I suppose) or two drives, in which case we can directly tell you steps needed to copy drive.

Comment: For example, `pv` won't care for the layout you have in case it is somehow wrong. See my answer here https://superuser.com/a/1116299/402107

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I want to know how I can fix this overlapping issue, as I can see from fdisk it seems that nvme0n1p2 and nvme0n1p2 are overlapping, is that normal or this is what is causing the problem? If so, how it can be fixed? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Thank you, good night.

Comment: If nothing else, you can reasonably safely delete partitions 5 and 2 since they jointly hold a single swap partition. That'll fix the overlap error but you will need to fix up the expectation of what's now a missing swap partition in the cloned image. Let's see if anyone else comes up with a cleaner solution

Comment: The swap partition which seems to be a logical partition seems to extend outside its container, the extended partition. This should not happen. Try to remove the swap partition, or as roaima suggests, remove also the extended partition. Then check the UUID in `/etc/fstab` and be prepared to set it when you create a new swap partition. Use `gparted` to create [a new extended partition and] a new partition in the extended partition and check that is is within the limits of the extended partition. Then use `mkswap -U UUID-matching-fstab /dev/...`.

Comment: If you skip the extended partition, the swap partition will get another partition number, but the UUID is the important thing, that should match what is in `/etc/fstab'

Comment: @Tak remove your swap and logical partition and then try; you can always create a swap partition when needed; i think it's useless cloning swap - it's unnecessarily increases image size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer adapted from: [how-to-fix-overlapped-partitions-in-the-mbr-table](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437272/how-to-fix-overlapped-partitions-in-the-mbr-table/437613#437613). You can try this but i think much be easier solution to just delete swap and logical partition

---

> Fixing the partition table with `sfdisk`:
>
> 1. Boot with live Ubuntu disk;
> 2. Confirm the problem on your disk device, here `/dev/sda` with `parted` e.g.
>
>    ```
>     sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print which should show:
>
>     Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.
>    ```
> 3. Partition details can be checked with:
>
>    ```
>     sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sda
>    ```

which, for you, according to your post is:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953,9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6e617337

Device         Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *          2048 1998407679 1998405632 952,9G 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p2      1998409726 2000397734    1988009 970,7M  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      1998409728 2000408575    1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

> 4. Checking the overlaps: You can see that your extended partition `/dev/nvme0n1p2` is smaller than your swap partition
>    `/dev/nvme0n1p5`.

To make things more clear
your swap partition is inside the that extended partition and hence it's size should be smaller that extended partition size ideally.But in your case **swap size is greater than logical partition size** itself.

```
Device            Size  

/dev/nvme0n1p2    970,7M  
/dev/nvme0n1p5    976M
```

or in other words end sector of nvme0n1p2 should be greater than end sector of nvme0n1p5.But in your case

> **nvme0n1p2<sub>end</sub>** = 2000397734
>
> **nvme0n1p5<sub>end</sub>** = 2000408575

and hence the problem.

Now you can simply solve it by reducing you swap partition size simply using gparted. (~ 600MB - 700MB)

OR  you can use command line tools :

```
sfdisk
```

---

Using sfdisk

> 5. As suggested in the [documentation](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#overlapping-partitions) that - *"In cases where we do not know if the starting or ending sector is the problem,
>    we assume that the starting sector of each partition is correct, and
>    that the ending sector might be in error"*, we assume that the
>    starting sector of extended partition `nvme0n1p2` is correct. Hence we will
>    be looking to change the end sector of swap partition `nvme0n1p5`.
>
> Calculations:
>
> **nvme0n1p5<sub>newEnd</sub>** = **nvme0n1p2<sub>end</sub>** - 1 =
> 2000397734 - 1 = 2000397733
>
> **nvme0n1p5<sub>newSize</sub>** =  **nvme0n1p5<sub>newEnd</sub>** -  **nvme0n1p5<sub>start</sub>** =
> 2000397733 - 1998409728  = ***1988005***

> 6. Dumping a copy of the partition table in an file using the `sfdisk` command:
>
> `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda` should dump the partition table details.
> This can be dumped to a file, which after necessary corrections are
> made, can be fed back to `sfdisk`. [**To OP:** Please edit your
> Question and include the output of `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda`]
>
> Dump a copy of partition table with:
>
> ```
>     sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda-backup.txt
> ```

> 7. Open the file with root privilege, created in the previous step, using text editor of your choice. In the example I'll use `nano`.
>
>    ```
>     sudo nano sda-backup.txt (`sda-backup.txt` assuming the file is in the current directory, else repalce it with the file's absolute
>    ```
>
> path.)
>
> Change the old size of `nvme0n1p5` (`1998848`) to the corrected size
> (`1988005`) so that your new partition table dump would look
> something like:

**output not attached by op**

> Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for `nano`) and close the
> editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for `nano`).
>
> 8. Feeding back the corrected partition details to the partition table using the `sfdisk` command:
>
>    ```
>     sudo sfdisk /dev/sda < sda-backup.txt
>    ```
> 9. Confirm if the problem is resolved by running `parted` on your disk device:
>
>    ```
>     sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print
>    ```
> 10. If step 9 confirm that the partition table is fixed, you can then use **GParted** or other partition editors with the device.
>
> ---
>
> The GParted documentition also suggests an alternative method, using
> [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to scan the disk
> device to rebuild the partition table. The testdisk application is
> included on [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). So if you
> are not comfortable with the command-line way, you can try the
> alternative.
>
> <sub>[source](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#overlapping-partitions)</sub>

---

Using Gparted

```
unmount your swap partition before continuing
```

1. current state

[image]

2. resize the root partition

[image]

3. root partition before resize

[image]

4. root partition after resize

[image]

5. created empty space after root partition

[image]

6. deleting swap

[image]

7. delaeting logical partition

[image]

8. all partitions removed except root

[image]

9. create new logical partition

[image]

10. leave some free space before partition (so it doesn't overlap) and select partition type as `Extended partition`

[image]

11. this is how it should look now

[image]

12. create swap partition

[image]

13. leave some free space after partition so it doesn't exceed and select filesysytem as `linux swap`

[image]

14. this is how it should look now

[image]

15. copy the UUID of your new swap and replace it in your `/etc/fstab`

[image]

---

Comment: I will hereby flag this answer for Need of moderation - deletion. IMHO, please note we do not support directly nor indirectly copy-pasting of someone else's hard work.

Comment: @roaima i was in mid of editing {already stated} and that's why whole answer was in quote to let anyone know that this answer has been take from other questions; i have not directly copied but anyway i have stated the source as per the rules

Comment: @Madhubala What you could have done is commenting with the link of such answer. That would have been proper course of action for me personally.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak yeah you are correct but since the calculation part can't be written in comments {it did cost me time in that} i thought it would be good to write it as an answer ; anyway what should be i do - delete the answer ?

Comment: You've quoted your reference now, thank you +1 for the extra customisation

Comment: @Madhubala why don't I do it the same way in your answer to my other question using gparted. So I delete the swap partition the the logical, then I reduce the size of the ext4 parition a bit (50GB) then for the unallocated space I create new logical parition then new swap? I just wonder :) (note: this workstation is very critical to me, so if there is a possibility of this messing it up I prefer not to do it :) )

Comment: @Tak yeah that should work ; you should have thought of this at first place when resizing your root and creating swap but nevermind; also change tthe UUID of /etc/fstab once done (like previous one); good luck liitle one );

Comment: @Madhubala can you add this Gparted way it to the answer? :)

Comment: @Tak done; feel free to mark answer as accepted if it helped